# Passing the address of a pointer as a parameter

Tags: c++, pointers

What is the point passing the address of a pointer as a parameter? For example:

```
int *ptr_one;
ptr_one = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

then function is being called as the following:

```
func(&ptr_one);
```

Note the function argument is as follow:

```
func(int **ptr)
{
......
}
```

Comment: For one of many examples, when you pass the address of {anything}, that function may modify the caller's {anything}.  This practice (and your code) is more C than C++.

Comment: One typical example is when you add an element to a list, you need to pass its `head` (pointer) and be able to modify it. Using a single pointer is a very very common mistake that creates lots of headaches. But the way to go is with C++ references, i.e. pass the pointer by reference, like `func(int* & ptr)`

Comment: In modern C++ we rarely need pointers anyway, so passing them (by whatever means) is fairly rare to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to modify the pointer itself, then you need to pass it either by reference, or by the address of the pointer. E.g.,

```
func(int **ptr)
{
    free(ptr);

    ptr = new int[2]; //side note: use new instead of malloc in C++
                      //memory allocated with new is deallocated with
                      //delete
}
```

In C, passing the address of a pointer was the only way you could allocate or deallocate the memory of that pointer in a function. In C++, however, it is usually better to pass by reference instead. So a C++ version of your code would look like:

```
int *ptr = new int;
func(ptr);
delete ptr;

void func(int *&ptr) {
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: My pointer is pointing to a list of entries and the function will keep modifying the head of the pointer every time I call it. I guess that is what you meant by modifying the pointer it self. right ?

Comment: @Anas: Yep. If you just passed in `head`, the pointer would not change in the calling code, just in the function.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of passing a pointer to a pointer is so that the pointer variable can be modified.

Recall, from the C-style of coding, that a parameter can be modified by passing the address or pointer to the parameter.  If the parameter is an int that needs to be modified, a pointer to the integer is passed.  Likewise, if a pointer parameter will be modified by the function, it was passed by pointer to pointer (or address of pointer).